# Laravel - fazer DB::table() sem usar o Join

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estou mexendo com laravel e estou aprendendo orientação a objeto e queria fazer um select sem usar o join porem como e orientado a objeto e sei pouco n estou conseguindo.

como sou acostumado a usar:

```
$results = DB::select("SELECT u.foto, u.Ninck,o.Idsala,p.Aceitou, u.Id FROM Onsalas o , Usuarios u, Partidas p WHERE (o.Idusuario=u.Id) AND (u.Id != $Id) AND(o.Idsala = $sala) AND ((p.IdDesafiado = $Idop)  OR (p.IdDesafiante = $Idop))  ");
```

tentei fazer de farias formas porem todas sem sucesso

algumas formas que tentei:

```
 $results =  DB::table(' \'Onsalas\' , \'Usuarios\' ')      
                        ->select('Onsala.Id')->get();

 $results =  DB::table('Onsalas' , 'Usuarios')      
                        ->select('Onsala.Id')->get();



$results =  DB::table('Onsalas')->table( 'Usuarios')      
                        ->select('Onsala.Id')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá

Poderias usar isto, contudo deverias dar uma olhadela ao eloquent.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent

```
$users = DB::table('Onsalas')
    ->join('Usuarios', 'Onsalas.Idusuario', '=', 'Usuarios.Id')
    ->join('Partidas', 'Partidas.Idusuario', '=', 'Usuarios.Id')
    ->select('Usuarios.foto', 'Usuarios.Ninck', 'Onsalas.Idsala', 'Partidas.Aceitou', 'Usuarios.Id')
    ->where('Usuarios.Id', '=', $Id)
    ->where('Onsalas.Idsala', '=', $sala)
    ->where(function ($query) use ($Idop) {
        $query->where('Partidas.IdDesafiado', '=', $Idop)
            ->orWhere('Partidas.IdDesafiante', '=', $Idop)
    })
    ->get();
```

Atualização não usando joins:

```
$resultados = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT u.foto, u.Ninck,o.Idsala,p.Aceitou, u.Id FROM Onsalas o , Usuarios u, Partidas p WHERE (o.Idusuario=u.Id) AND (u.Id != $Id) AND(o.Idsala = $sala) AND ((p.IdDesafiado = $Idop)  OR (p.IdDesafiante = $Idop))"));
```

Comment: ai vc usou o Join estava querendo fazer sem usar o Join